# Demo of dgrid not displaying in a Dojo/Dijit/ContentPane

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dijit.layout

I'm trying to display a simple dgrid as per the first demo on this page:
http://dgrid.io/tutorials/1.0/grids_and_stores/

The only trick is that I'm trying to put it inside an existing structure of containers. So I tried the onFocus event of the container, but when I click on that container, the grid is not showing, and no console.log message appears.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:"CustomersGrid"'>
<script type='dojo/on' data-dojo-event='onFocus'>
    require([
        'dstore/RequestMemory',
        'dgrid/OnDemandGrid'
    ], function (RequestMemory, OnDemandGrid) {
        // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
        var dom = require('dojo/dom');  
        console.log("onFocus event for CustomersGrid ContentPane");             
        dom.byId('studentLastname').value  = 'test onFocus event';
        var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
            collection: new RequestMemory({ target: 'hof-batting.json' }),
            columns: {
                first: 'First Name',
                last: 'Last Name',
                totalG: 'Games Played'
            }
        }, 'grid');

        grid.startup();
    });
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: No errors found.

Comment: Are you getting the data correctly? Also, have you checked the DOM structure? Is the grid node placed over there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make it work by:

- setting the id of the div to 'grid'
- adding a "Click me" span (or I had nothing to focus on)
- changing the event name from 'onFocus' to 'focus'

Then, the grid appears when you click on the 'Click me' text (to activate focus).

Below the corresponding full source page (for my environment):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Neal Walters stask overflow test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dgrid/css/dgrid.css" media="screen">

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id='grid' data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:"CustomersGrid"'>
    <span>click me!</span>
    <script type='dojo/on' data-dojo-event='focus'>
        require([
            'dstore/RequestMemory',
            'dgrid/OnDemandGrid'
        ], function (RequestMemory, OnDemandGrid) {
            // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
            var dom = require('dojo/dom');  
            console.log("onFocus event for CustomersGrid ContentPane");             
            //dom.byId('studentLastname').value  = 'test onFocus event';
            var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                collection: new RequestMemory({ target: 'hof-batting.json' }),
                columns: {
                    first: 'First Name',
                    last: 'Last Name',
                    totalG: 'Games Played'
                }
            }, 'grid');

            grid.startup();
        });
    </script>
    </div>
    <script src="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dojo/dojo.js"  data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require(["dojo/parser", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(parser){
            parser.parse();
        });
    </script>
 </body>
```

The above is using declarative syntax. Alternatively, you may consider going programmatic, as in the source code below where the grid appears on loading the page. Also whereas with the declarative syntax above a breakpoint inside the script is ignored (using firefox), it is activated as expected with the programmatic syntax:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Neal Walters stask overflow test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dgrid/css/dgrid.css" media="screen">

</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id='grid' data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props='title:"CustomersGrid"'></div>
    <script src="dojo-release-1.12.2-src/dojo/dojo.js"  data-dojo-config="async:true"></script>
    <script>
        require([
            'dstore/RequestMemory',
            'dgrid/OnDemandGrid'
        ], function (RequestMemory, OnDemandGrid) {
            // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
            var dom = require('dojo/dom');  
            console.log("onFocus event for CustomersGrid ContentPane");             
            //dom.byId('studentLastname').value  = 'test onFocus event';
            var grid = new OnDemandGrid({
                collection: new RequestMemory({ target: 'hof-batting.json' }),
                columns: {
                    first: 'First Name',
                    last: 'Last Name',
                    totalG: 'Games Played'
                }
            }, 'grid');

            grid.startup();
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You are amazing!  Thanks!  So are these tricks require to get it to work in the container? Or were there bugs in the code I copied?  I guess I should have tried it in a non-container as well.  I'll have to lookup onFocus vs Focus.

Comment: Would an onLoad/load type event make the form autofill when the container opens?

Comment: Your example also lead me to see I was missing the css for the datagrid: <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dgrid/css/dgrid.css"/>

Comment: Thanks for the compliment :-). Indeed these were bugs in your code, nothing related to the container. Not sure what you mean with autofill the form. If you provide the adequate target (hof-battting.json in your case), the grid data will show-up with the grid: on focus for the declarative version, on loading the page for the programmatic one (as in the tutorial).